# PM2 - How can i remove the identifier from the log file name

Tags: javascript, logging, pm2

Im trying to remove the service identifier from the log file name.

Example:

My `ecosystem.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
        name: "My Service",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        max_memory_restart: "150M",
        error: "/var/log/pm2/my-service.log",
        out: "/var/log/pm2/my-service.log",
        max_restarts: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, i expect a log file named: `/var/log/pm2/my-service.log`.

But this is what it generates: `/var/log/pm2/my-service-4.log`.

I'm using pm2 version `3.5.0`, I've just upgraded it from version `2.10.4`

Node version: `v8.16.0`

**UPDATE 1:**

I've also tried using different parameters like `merge_logs`, here's an example of that version:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
        name: "My Service",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        max_memory_restart: "150M",
        error: "/var/log/pm2/my-service.log",
        out: "/var/log/pm2/my-service.log",
        max_restarts: 10,
        merge_logs: true
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems like pm2 it's completely ignoring what i set in the `error` and `output` options.
I've tried changing those options to `error_file` and `out_file` and then reloading the logs with `pm2 reloadLogs` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this.

It looks like pm2 is caching the ecosystem file, and it completely ignores the changes on the file once you start it.

For making pm2 reload all the config again, you have to remove all the services and start them again.

Here's what i did:

```sh
pm2 delete all
pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js
```

After doing this, it reloaded the config and it started writing to the correct files.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using a log suffix for your app. See the [pm2 documentation here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#logs-suffix).

> You can disable automatic ID suffixs on logs (e.g. `app-name-ID.log`) by passing enabling the option `merge_logs: true`

So, your env file should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
        name: "My Service",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        max_memory_restart: "150M",
        error: "/var/log/pm2/my-service.log",
        out: "/var/log/pm2/my-service.log",
        max_restarts: 10,
        merge_logs: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: OK. Please update your question with the env file that you have tried. This is exactly the setting I am using and it is working. Perhaps the structure of your pm2.env file is not correct.